# How to pass special character via url in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fragment-identifier

I want to have a url link like: /Posts/Post/1#comments

Where: Posts - controller name, Post - action name, 1 - id parameter

I am using following code in my View:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Post", "Posts", new { id = @item.PostId + "#comments" })">Comments</a>
```

As a result I have: /Posts/Post/1%23comments

What to do to pass '#' char instead of "%23"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looking for:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Post", "Posts", new { id = item.PostId })#comments" ...></a>
```

`#` is for hash, so to send it server-side (which `Url.Action` is expecting) means encoding it. If you're looking to supplement the client experience, don't include it in your `Url.Action` (or create a special overload that accepts a fragment identifier and outputs it un-touched).

Comment: That's the answer for my question. Thanks!

Comment: Technically: "fragment identifier", not hash

Comment: @MarcGravell: Tomäto Tomâto. I guess I group it given the [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash) labels it "hash" (even though its a hash + fragment). But I've re-worded it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

for that data to be part of the *action*, `%23` is correct; if the `#` represents a fragment - *it isn't part of the "action"*. A `#` in a url denotes the client-side fragment - typically used for jumping to an element in a document by `id` (the server never sees anything after the `#` in a url)

See also: [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) (look at the url)

Comment: Yes, but in fact I would like to jump to an element in document... The question is how to do it?

Comment: @user1334190 then: that isn't part of the "action", since the action is server-side, and the server *never sees fragments*; add the `#comments` separately: `href="@(Url.Action(...))#comments"`

Comment: href="@(Url.Action(...))#comments" is a simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Html.ActionLink` with proper oveload (`fragment` parameter) instead of building link manually.

```
@Html.ActionLink(
           "Comments", 
           "Post", 
           "Posts", null, null, 
           "comments", // fragment part
           new { id = @item.PostId }, 
           new { })
```

Comment: For ref [`Html.ActionLink(HtmlHelper,string,string,string,string,string,string,object,object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522(v=vs.118).aspx) & [`Html.ActionLink(HtmlHelper,string,string,string,string,string,string,RouteValueDictionary,IDictionary<string,object>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522(v=vs.118).aspx).